# Using LIKE in db_query in D7

Tags: 7, database

I have a query like this in Drupal 6:

```
$sql = 'SELECT sid, score FROM search_index WHERE word LIKE "%%%s%%"';
$result = db_query($sql,$search_term);
```

And it worked fine, but now I'm upgrading to Drupal 7.

I read up and this is supposed to work, but it's not:

```
$sql = 'SELECT sid, score FROM search_index WHERE word LIKE "%:term"';
$result = db_query($sql,array(':term'=>$search_term));
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT sid, score FROM {search_index} WHERE word LIKE :term';
 $result = db_query($sql, array(':term' => '%' . db_like($search_term)));
```

Comment: db_like ...? Why Drupal, why would you do that?

Comment: Yes, Drupal introduced a new db api in 7, such as `db_select()`, `db_insert()`, `db_update()`, `db_condition()`, `db_like()`, etc. Instead of using `db_query()`, it recommends to use `db_select()`. See here http://drupal.org/developing/api/database, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7

Comment: @Coomie If you look at [db_like](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_like/7), you will see that the escaping is done specifically by the DB layer on a per-engine basis.  This is done for portability reasons.

Comment: Is it correct that the first line ends with a comma?

Answer (score 0):

If you followup the the following link,
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7
This will tell you that,

> Note that placeholders should be a "complete" value. For example, when running a LIKE query the SQL wildcard character, %, should be part of the value, not the query itself.

So

```
SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title%;
```

Is incorrect.

The query should be

```
SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title;
```